# Is there any possibility to call preference-headers in a fragment?

Tags: android, preference-headers

I'm having an android application which has only one activity. Any UI changes etc are made on fragments. But I want to implement a preference settings screen as tablet style view.

[image]

The problem is that i have to implement that feature in fragment. As I see everywhere - everybody add it by using activity (PreferenceActivity).
Is there any hack or something to be able to call "onBuildHeaders" and "loadHeadersFromResource"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the preferred way is a preference fragment. and most of the activities are really use fragments internally.  this is a useful link;

[Prefs](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c)

[example](https://github.com/XinyueZ/preference-demo)

[this might be closer](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/01/preferenceactivity-preferencefragment_28.html)

Comment: I wrote "Fragment" by having on mind "PreferenceFragment".
But there is no "onBuildHeaders" function, so cannot load preference-headers.

Comment: I added a link that might be closer to what you need.

Comment: Still not. Don't you see in these examples that preference-headers are loaded in activity?
I can't do that. I need to build multi-pane in main fragment...

Comment: In the 3rd link the post uses an activity to display the headers and a fragment to display the preferences for the selected header. That's all I found.